# knockout.js mapping custom events

Tags: mapping, knockout.js

I try to build a simple blog application with knockout.js and rails.
(knockout v1.3 beta, knockout mapping plugin v2.0.2)

```
<h3>Posts</h3>

<ul data-bind="foreach: posts">
    <li>
        <input data-bind="value: title" />
    </li>
</ul>

<script>
    var posts = ko.mapping.fromJSON('<%= @posts.to_json.html_safe %>'); 
    ko.applyBindings(posts);
</script>
```

this displays alle the posts from a rails app, no problem so far.
but now i want to add a custom event to the posts, e.g. a remove event.

i tried this:

```
<h3>Posts</h3>

<ul data-bind="foreach: posts">
    <li>
        <input data-bind="value: title" />
    </li>
</ul>

<script>
    var posts = ko.mapping.fromJSON('<%= @posts.to_json.html_safe %>', { remove: function() {
      alert('working');
    }); 
    ko.applyBindings(posts);
</script>
```

but i get an error "remove is not defined"

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you could just add the function to the posts viewModel, like this:

```
var posts = ko.mapping.fromJSON('<%= @posts.to_json.html_safe %>');
posts.remove = function() { alert('working'); }
```